# Concatenate two or more object in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to combine all objects in one variable.

```
public ActionResult findAllDevices(string deviceOne  , string deviceTwo , string deviceThree)
{
    var foundedDeviceOne = DB.Prouducts.Where(x => x.ProductModel == deviceOne).FirstOrDefault();
    var foundedDeviceTwo = DB.Prouducts.Where(x => x.ProductModel == deviceTwo).FirstOrDefault();
    var foundedDeviceThree = DB.Prouducts.Where(x => x.ProductModel == deviceThree).FirstOrDefault();
    var allFoundedDevices = foundedDeviceOne + foundedDeviceTwo + foundedDeviceThree // want like this 
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You create a list and add them in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can create a list and put your values in it:

Like this:

```
var t = new List<Prouducts>() { foundedDeviceOne , foundedDeviceThree , foundedDeviceThree  };
```

Comment: In my vs2015 not getting data type in List<Product> like this

Comment: It is product in model products is for DB context for entity framework.

Comment: what is the datatype for foundedDeviceOne . create a list for that. You might have to add reference of that class to this file

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
var allFoundedDevices = foundedDeviceOne.Union(foundedDeviceTwo).Union(foundedDeviceThree);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a ViewModel that wraps all 3 objects in one and then send that class in the View and access it in your .cshtml.